# Web Services Between Java Jersey and Microsoft .NET

Tags: java, .net, web-services, jersey

I need to consume web services from a .NET web service and serve up a web service to a .NET client. I really like Jersey on the Java side but I'm not a .NET developer and don't know much about the microsoft stack.

The team doing the .NET side doesn't have a strong preference as to how the server/client is developed on their side. Is there a .NET web service implementation that already plays nicely with Jersey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [NancyFx](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) or [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/) (developed by a StackOverflow employee). It kind of similar to Jersey, but in a simpler way, and definitely easier to work with than the classic WCF services.

Comment: Service Stack looks like a perfect candidate. Thank you!